# Is limit of a an increasing function is a bound?

Tags: calculus

I have a function $f(x)$ which is defined for positive $x$. I know that $f'\geq 0 $ and $lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = m$. Can I say that $f(x)$ is bounded by $m$?

Comment: Your title says increasing, but the body says $f' \le 0$.  Should that be $f' \ge 0?$

Comment: Yes, it's increasing. (confused ```\leq``` and ```\geq```)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  "$f(x)$ is bounded by $m$" (for $m \geq 0$) means that all values of $f$ have magnitude no greater than $m$.  That is, $-m \leq f(x) \leq m$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$.

You *can* say $f$ is lower bounded by $m$.  (In this Question, that claim depends on the fact that $f$ is monotonically decreasing.  In general, a function can oscillate around its limit at infinity, for example, $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ has limit $0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, but passes above and below $0$, so $0$ neither bounds this function above nor below.)

Answer (score 1):

If $f $ is decreasing,  then $m=\inf f ((0, \infty )) $

If $f $ is increasing,  then $m= \sup f ((0,\infty)) $